# How can I check if the character from a user- inputted string (first string) is present on the second string?

Tags: java

We have to write a program that inputs two String values. And this is the condition:

1. If the third character of the first string is present on the second string then do this code...

I tried using the .contains() method but there is an error. I also don't know how to apply loops because the output is being printed several times.  What should I do?

The error says "The method contains (CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)"

```
System.out.println("Input String 1:");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = sc1.nextLine();   
    
    System.out.println("Input String 2:");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str2 = sc2.nextLine();
    
    char third = str1.charAt(2);
            if (str2.contains(third)) {
                str1 = str1.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "*");
                str1.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "*");
                System.out.println(str1.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: What error do you get? Share staktrace please.

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(third)`

Comment: @Juro have you tried my method yet? That should work

Comment: Great. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)'s the doc of CharSequence if you wanna read up on it a bit. [Also a comparation to Strings](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-sequence-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
String first = "xyz";
String nthChar = Character.toString(first.charAt(2);
String second = "aaaaaaaz";
if(second.indexOf(nthChar) != -1){
    // nth character from 'first' exists in 'second'
    // do whatever
}
```